# How can I override the behavior of valueOf() as a prototype of the Number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, prototype, prototypejs, value-of

**I was given a task to understand the .toString and .valueOf methods, who calls them, where they are used, how they work, how they are called and how to change calling sequence.**

I am getting an error when I trying to override this:

```
Number.prototype.toString = function () {
  return "This is the number: " + this
};

Number.prototype.valueOf = function () {
  //console.log(this)
  return this;
}

console.log(new Number(33).toString());
console.log(new Number(34).valueOf())
```

Js returns an error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, how can I override value of to return, for example, string - 'The number is ${this}'

I've found out that everything is working if I remove `console.log(new Number(33).toString());`

I have tried to console.log this and got such output:
[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp4yV.png)

Comment: @David I've updated the question and figured out that it's not working only if I console.log new Number(33).toString() before that

Comment: The `toString` has implicit recursion due to the string concatenation of the `this`.

Comment: @Danny, so how can I override this two methods in proper way?

Comment: It would help people provide you with ideas if you would take the time to describe *why* you want to do this. What is your goal? What does this mean in the context of the project you're working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really do not want to give this advice, and do not know why you wouldn't declare a sub `Class` that has its prototype set to `Object.create(Number.prototype)` but if you want to do it on all Numbers, than you can go with a monkey patch:

```js
Number.prototype.toString = (function(f){return function(){return `whatever ${f.call(this)}`}})(Number.prototype.toString)

Number.prototype.valueOf = (function(f){return function(){return f.call(this)}})(Number.prototype.valueOf)
```

change the `valueOf` and `toString` to whatever you need.

Warning: this is not good.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know that it is better not to override these methods, but it was my task. Also, I have one more question. We override these methods, and they only work for numbers that were created using the constructor (new Number(10)), am I right? Do we have any opportunity to change the behavior of the numbers that were expressed in a literal form during implicit converting?

Comment: @yarslvd when you write something like `(17).valueOf()` the `17` (number primitive) is automatically converted to a Number instance.

Comment: @Pointy, Yeah, I understand that, but if, for example, console.log("3" + myNum), where the number is 'const myNum = 10' in that case, how is the number converted to a string?

Comment: @yarslvd any time a number is converted to a string, the `.toString()` method is called.

Comment: @Pointy But why is our overridden method `.toString()` not used when we are using a literal expression of the number?

Comment: @yarslvd what makes you think it isn't?

Comment: @yarslvd, Pointy meant any time you use numbers, whether declared via new Number(...) or just plainly like (5), it implicitly converted to a number object if the engine detects you are trying to call a method on it, because `this` needs to be an object. BY default, on objects, `valueOf` is preferred over `toString`, that's what the engine will do for instance if you do: `const x = {}; x.valueOf = () => 5; x + "a"` will return '5a' because `valueOf` of x will be called and then subsequently `toString` of Number(5) is called implicitly

Comment: @Pointy I we call (20).toString() everything works fine, but when the number is converted using string interpolation `console.log('${20}')` it's not working. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/uLgvftpj/3/

Comment: Primitive data types use the internal references for string conversion. So to coerce them to use what you assigned to Number.prototype, you need to convert them to an object. One way it new Number, like you did. So in your jsfiddle, change `const num2 = 20;` to `const num2 = Object(20);` and it will work

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin, thank you!

Comment: @Pointy I have one more question can you help me? How can we reprogram compiler instructions to call the valueOf/toString methods? Compiler instructions that let the compiler know when it can call a method on its own.

Comment: @yarslvd those rules are part of the language specification and cannot be changed. You can of course explicitly call those methods whenever you want to.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. It was the question from the internship, and I found out that the right answer was to add the @@toPrimitive method. I think the formulation of the question is kinda confusing and unclear.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a `Number` using `new`, you create a *`Number object`*, which is not a primitive - see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number). That may be the origin of the error.

I think there are better ways to override `Number` methods, without polluting its `prototype`.

One of those is for example creating a custom `Number` object, using a closure to hold its value and extending that with some functions. That way you don't need  `protoype` (or `this` for that matter). Something like:

```js
function XNumber(nr = 0) {

  // the number function encloses [nr]
  const number = nrGiven => {
    nr = nrGiven;
  }
  
  const myNumberExtensions = {
    toString() { return `This is the number ${nr}`},
    set value(val) { nr = val; },
    clone(value) { return XNumber(value ?? nr); },
    increment(withValue = 1) { nr += withValue; return number; },
    valueOf() { return nr; },
  };
  
  // because Function is just another object,
  // you can extend it with custom methods
  Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(myNumberExtensions))
    .forEach( ([key, descriptor]) => { 
      Object.defineProperty(number, key, descriptor); 
    }
  );
  
  return number;
}

const myNr1 = XNumber(41);
const myNr2 = myNr1.clone().increment();

console.log(myNr1.toString());
// toString automatically when within a (template) string:
console.log(`${myNr1}`);

console.log(myNr2.valueOf());
// valueOf automatically when appended to a string
console.log(""+myNr2);
```

Comment: Not that I agree with modifying the Number prototype, but a feature that would have is that expressions like `(x * 2).toString()` would pick up the modified method automatically.

Comment: @Pointy sure, everything has a price ;/ `XNumber(x*2).toString()` would work though.

Comment: Thanks, but I have an exact task to override these methods to understand how JS works)